# Is "decide to give" a compound verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I know that two verbs joined by a conjunction and referring to the same subject make a compound verb:

- The dog **ran and jumped** in the park.
- I **read a book and listened to music** while I waited.
- The boys **whispered and giggled** as their aunt scolded them.

And I know that *to be*, *to have*, or a modal verb paired with a verb is an auxiliary verb:

- My mother **is sleeping**.
- The dog **had bitten** the mailman.
- You **should watch** this movie.

But what about when an infinitive follows a conjugated verb? Are the following sentences compound verbs, auxiliary verbs, or something else?

- He **decided to give** them a tour.
- I **need to go** to the store.
- Many older people **prefer to write** cursive.

Comment: Well, if the two verbs in a compound verb must share the same subject, then "decided to give" can't be compound, because the subject of "give" is "tour" and the subject of "decided" is "give". Unfortunately, I don't know what these constructions are actually called.

Comment: Wouldn't "tour" be the object, not the subject, of "give"?

Comment: Oh, whoops! Yes.

Comment: Well, "compound verb" isn't a very helpful term; it just means `Verb` _and/or_ `Verb`. What you're describing is what's called a complement clause governed by a main verb. Complements are much more important than compounds. We say that _decide_ has an infinitive complement clause _(for him) to give them a tour_ and _need_ has an infinitive complement clause _(for me) to go to the store_, for instance. There are [four kinds of complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf), and infinitive clause is one of them. Which one gets used depends on what the main verb is.

Comment: In this case _need_ is lexical verb (when followed by to-infinitive), although it can be semi-modal. _Decide_ and _prefer_ are copulative verbs of incomplete predication that require lexical verb.

Comment: @JohnLawler That seems exactly right! If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Kathy: "copulative verbs of incomplete predication"? That sounds like a name from an official verb list. Where does it come from and how many other kinds of verbs are there on that list? I would say that _decide_ is an active mental verb that takes either a tensed complement or an infinitive complement with A-Equi, while _prefer_ is a stative mental verb with two potential complements, since it's an implied comparison.  _Prefer_ can take an infinitive or gerund complement with A-Equi; or it can take a _that_-complement, with either a tensed verb or an infinitive.

Comment: @JohnLawler, we use this term at University and I've found the term now on the internet where you can see some more examples such as _seem_ and _appear_ - [verbs of incomplete predication](http://www.englishgrammar.org/verbs-incomplete-predication). Although _decide_ and _prefer_ are not on the list, they cannot stand on its own because you cannot just say _I decide_ or _I prefer_, they require a complement which is, in this case, a lexical verb in its full infinitive form.

Comment: @Kathy: Thank you for the pointer. It's traditionalist nonsense, I'm afraid. _Seem_ is an intransitive verb with a clause for its subject (**That he is here seems*), but the clause must be moved, either by Extraposition (_It seems that he is here_) or by A-Raising (_He seems to be here_). Very like _appear_. It doesn't belong in the same class with decide, which is A-Equi. Details on [Equi and Raising, with solved exercises, here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Comment: @Kathy: The problem with that kind of analysis is that it doesn't make the distinctions needed because it can't go into detail -- it's defined in a vague and impressionistic way so that nobody can tell what verbs belong to the class. Grammatical terms need to be defined in grammatical terms, not in terms like "a complete thought", which is utterly meaningless -- thoughts are unobservable and their completeness is a matter of personal opinion, not fact. So I'm afraid it shouldn't be used at all; certainly not in college.

Comment: @JohnLawler, how would you then call this type of verbs which are lexical, but require some sort of complement in order the sentence to have a meaning? If we can classify all verbs in English as lexical, copulative, auxiliary or modal, into which category would _decide_, _seem_, _feel_ belong? For example _The velvet felt soft against my skin_ or _I wanted to taste the pie_. I'm just writing what they taught us. Whether this should or should not be taught, it is not the matter of my opinion.

Comment: I'd call _seem_ and _appear_ intransitive predicates with subject complements. They're unusual in that most such predicates are predicate adjectives or nouns like _possible, likely, unnecessary, sad, difficult, a shame, disgusting,_ etc. Extraposition or Raising or Tough-Movement generally will move the subject complement (or at least most of it) to the end of the sentence, leaving a dummy subject of some sort, like _it_.

Comment: Oh, and I **wouldn't** "classify all verbs in English as lexical, copulative, auxiliary or modal". Modals **are** auxiliaries, for starts, and there are no "copulative" verbs; they're an invention of puzzled teachers who want to label everything they don't understand. Predicates in English can be classified into verbs, predicate nouns, and predicate adjectives; verbs can further be classified many ways, but the way you mentioned is not one of them. So you shouldn't worry about where the verbs fit -- the answer is they don't fit. The truth about English grammar often comes as a shock. Sorry.

Comment: "A copular (or linking) verb is complemented by a subject predicative in sentence or clause structure. The most common copular verb is be; others include become (my friend), feel (tired), get (ready), seem (happy). A copular prepositional verb is a prepositional verb (combination of verb plus preposition) that is complemented by a subject predicative: sound like (you), turn into (a monster), serve as (mitigating circumstances)."
(Sidney Greenbaum, Oxford English Grammar. Oxford Univ. Press, 1996). **Copular verbs do exist.** Do some research before giving your opinion.

Comment: @Kathy You probably don't know this, but John Lawler was professor of linguistics at the University of Michigan for a few decades. He's the only user on this site who can quite literally cite himself. In other words, [John's opinion qualifies as research](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/LawlerPublications.html).

Answer (score 1):

When two words are combined without a conjunction to form a single word, that is a compound, in the way the term "compound" is usually used in grammar.  None of your examples is like that, and so I would not call any of them a compound.

The Wikipedia article on [English compound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound) is pretty good, I think.

Comment: Compound subjects and compound verbs are not single words. Here's some information about compound subjects (http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/compound_subject.htm) and compound verbs (http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/compound-verb.html).

Comment: That is true, partly.  Using "compound" as an adjective, a compound subject is not a single word (because a subject is a phrase).  A "verb compound" is a single word, but "compound verb" is an ambiguous term.  It can mean a single word, like "outsource" e.g., but it could also refer to two verbs connected by "and", like your "whispered and giggled" example.  I didn't think of the second interpretation when I gave my answer.